# Primitive polynomial

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Prove that $x^5 + x^2 + 1$ is a primitive polynomial over ${\mathbb F}_2$.

I have already proved that the above polynomial is irreducible. Do I have to exhaustively prove that the above polynomial does not divide $X^n + 1$ where $1 \le n < 31$ or is there a better way to prove this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of primitive?

Comment: Standard definition of primitive polynomial.

Comment: What is the "standard definition of primitive polynomial"?

Comment: @user100503 You are working over ${\mathbb F}_2$, right?

Comment: The standard definition might be that the gcd of the coefficients is $1$, which is trivially the case her.

Comment: I am working over F2

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Let $F$ be a finite field. What primitive means is that it is an irreducible polynomial such that a root $\alpha$ (and so any of its roots) is a generator of the multiplicative group $F(\alpha)^{\times}$ (which we know to be cyclic)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen (Yes, that is what I was trying to get at.)

Comment: Definition - An irreducible polynomial of degree m is said to be primitive if the smallest positive integer n for which the polynomial divides X^n + 1 is n = 2^m - 1

Comment: @user100503 I've edited my post. Next time please comment below the answer exactly what it is you don't like or understand about it, so that it can be improved.

Answer (score 9):

If $\alpha$ is a root of your polynomial, since the polynomial is irreducible, we know that ${\mathbb F}_2 (\alpha)$ is actually the finite field having $2^5$ elements, and hence we know $\alpha^{31} = 1$ becuase $31$ is the order of the multiplicative group of ${\mathbb F}_{2^5}$.

Now, what can the multplicative order of $\alpha$ be if $\alpha^{31} = 1$? 31 is a very special number.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_%28field_theory%29) is the definition of primitive polynomial I am using here.

**EDIT:** To make matters clear, assume $p(x) = x^5 + x^2 + 1$ divides $x^n + 1 = x^n - 1$ for some $n\in\{0,\ldots,30\}$, then necessarily $n\geq 5$ as $\deg p = 5$. Now, if $\alpha$ were a root of $p(x)$, then $\alpha^n - 1 = 0$ because $p(x) | (x^n - 1)$. Hence the multiplicative order of $\alpha$ must divide $n$.

However, as we saw above, the multiplicative order of $\alpha$ is either 1 or 31 since 31 is prime, if the order were $1$ then $\alpha=1$ which is impossible as $p(1)=1\neq 0$, and so the order of $\alpha$ is 31. So it is impossible that the order divide $n$ for any $n<31$, a contradiction to the previous paragraph.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the answer!