# What are prime and primitive polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

Please, I am not a mathematician so highly mathematical textbook language will not make sense, that is why I am forced to post this question here.

I am reading about Checksum and CRC data integrity techniques and I have come across the terms "primtive polynomial" and "prime polynomial". I will really appreciate if someone could give example of these and explain what makes them primitive and prime.

e.g about polynomials used in Cyclic Redundancy Check that are implemented using hardware feedback registers it says "The best ones are not necessarily prime (irreducible) nor primitive"

Comment: If you're going to quote someone, say who you're quoting... https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/pubs/KoopmanCRCWebinar9May2012.pdf

Answer (score 2):

A prime polynomial $f$ in $K[X]$ (where $K$ is a field, e.g. $k=\Bbb R$) is the same as an irreducible polynomial (because $K[X]$ is a UFD [= unique factorization domain]).

A polynomial $f$ is irreducible in $K[X]$ if the following holds : whenever you can write $f$ as a product $g \cdot h$, one of the two factors $g$ or $h$ is a non-zero constant.

For instance, $X^2+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb R[X]$, but $x^4+4=(x^2-2 x+2) (x^2+2 x+2)$ is not.

Factorising polynomials can be difficult in general. Over finite fields, there are [Berkelamp's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp's_algorithm) and [Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm). A polynomial of degree $≤3$ is irreducible if and only if it has no roots.

Some examples: $x^2+x+1 \in \Bbb F_2[X]$ is irreducible, because you can't write it as $(x-a)(x-b)$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb F_2[X]$. On the other hand, $x^4+x^2+1 \in \Bbb F_2[X]$ is *not* irreducible, since you can factor it as $(x^2+x+1)^2 =x^4+2 x^3+3 x^2+2 x+1$ (recall that $2=0$ in $\Bbb F_2$).

---

Let $\Bbb F_{p^n} = \text{GF}(p^n)$ be the field with $p^n$ elements, which is an extension of the field $\Bbb F_p$.

You may know that its multiplicative group is a cyclic group, say generated by some element $a$ : we have $(\Bbb F_{p^n})^* = \langle a \rangle$, so that $\Bbb F_{p^n} = \Bbb F_p(a)$.

Then a primitive polynomial $f \in \Bbb F_p[X]$, in that context, is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\Bbb F_p$.
In particular, a primitive polynomial is irreducible. However, the converse doesn't hold: for instance, $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb F_2$ but is [not a primitive polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePolynomial.html).

For examples about primitive polynomials, you can have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542121) question or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312186) one.

Comment: In the context of checksums, it seems much more likely that "primitive" is being used in the sense of being a generating element, aka http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePolynomial.html.  One typically only works with monic polynomials, so the above meaning of the term "primitive" seems useless here.

Comment: @ErickWong : oh thanks! I will correct my answer then. I didn't know about this terminology!

Comment: Thanks for the edit!  One part is slightly misleading: $\langle a \rangle = F_p(a)$.  The RHS is a field, but the LHS is a multiplicative group (so it excludes $0$).  Maybe a better choice of RHS would be $\{1,a,a^2,\ldots\}$?  Or the finite version $\{a^k: 0 \le k < p^n\}$.

Comment: @ErickWong : thank you for your remark. I was a bit too hasty… ! I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: Could you give some more examples for primitive and irreducible polynomials? This will only really make sense to me seeing examples...

Comment: *Ber**lek**amp's algorithm (not Berkelamp's)